# Show $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{2n \choose n}x^n=(1-4x)^{-1/2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, power-series

How do you prove that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{2n \choose n}x^n=(1-4x)^{-1/2}$?
I tried to identify the sum as a binomial series, but the $4$ and the $-1/2$ puzzle me.
(This series arises in studying the first passage time of a simple random walk.)

Comment: See Mike Spivey's comment here:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37971/identity-involving-binomial-coefficients

Comment: @Byron: Thanks, this answer my question.

Comment: If it were the usual sort of binomial series then the $2n$ that sits in the top position in $\dbinom{2n}{n}$ would be something that does not change as the $n$ in the expression $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30343/help-with-summing-a-power-series/30407#30407) of mine is related to your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The key identities are the [duplication formula for the factorial](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5.E5) (which I'll recast in a more convenient format):

$$\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{4^n}{\sqrt \pi}\frac{\left(n-\frac12\right)!}{n!}$$

and the [reflection formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5.E3)

$$\left(-n-\frac12\right)!\left(n-\frac12\right)!=(-1)^n\pi$$

Making the appropriate replacements, we obtain

$$\binom{2n}{n}=(-4)^n\frac{\sqrt \pi}{n!\left(-n-\frac12\right)!}=(-4)^n\frac{\left(-\frac12\right)!}{n!\left(-n-\frac12\right)!}=(-4)^n\binom{-\frac12}{n}$$

You can proceed from that...

Comment: It seems that the trick doesn't work on $\sum_n\binom{3n}nz^n$.

Comment: I think they are unrelated. Maybe *Zeilberger-Gosper's algorithm* on *CMath* works. I have not verified.

Comment: Hmm, yes, I was hasty there. There's the hypergeometric route, of course.

Answer (score 15):

Or, by definition.
\begin{eqnarray*}
{-1/2\choose n}&=&{(-1/2)(-1/2-1)(-1/2-2)\cdots(-1/2-[n-1])\over n!}\cr
&=&{(-1)^n\over 2^n} {(1)(3)(5)\cdots(2n-1)\over n!}\cr
&=&{(-1)^n\over 2^n} {(1)(3)(5)\cdots(2n-1)\over n!}\cdot{2^n n!\over 2^n n!}\cr 
&=&{(-1)^n\over 4^n} {2n\choose n}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

You can use generating functions. Get a relation between two successive coefficients and form a differential equation in terms of power series. Refer the book Generatingfunctionology by Herbert Wilf.