# Finding a closed form expression for this sum

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, power-series

For non-negative $n$, find
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}.
$$
I can't figure this out. Any ideas?

Comment: This is a well known example of an identity for which it is much easier to find a proof using generating functions than by a direct combinatorial argument. For the question of nonetheless giving a combinatorial argument, see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/37971 and its duplicate http://math.stackexchange.com/q/72367

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: nicely researched. Both of these answers were outlined in the first question you cite. I will close this, but not merge since these answers don't answer the original.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen How did you search for that? I didn't know how to search for it because there's no specific name or term associated with it. O.w. I'd just have to look through all the results one at a time.

Comment: Looking in my history, it appears that the fruitful search was on 'bijective proof Stanley' on this site. I knew this was an exercise in Stanley's EC1, but it was a bit of luck. I did change the title so as to contain 'central binomial' to help future searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum has the form $d_n = \sum_{k=0}^n c_k c_{n-k}$, where $c_k = \binom{2k}{k}$. The sum is known as the [Cauchy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product). The generating function for $d_n$ is the second power of the generating function of $c_n$.
$$
  \sum_{n=0}^\infty d_n x^n = \left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k x^k \right)^2 = \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}} \right)^2 = \frac{1}{1-4x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{2k} x^k
$$
Thus
$$
   \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2k}{k} \binom{2n-2k}{n-k} = 2^{2n}
$$

Comment: How do you know that the 2nd term is equal to $(1/\sqrt{1-4x})^2$?

Comment: @AlanH Because $\binom{2k}{k} = (-1)^k 4^k \binom{-1/2}{k}$ by using duplication formula, and thus $$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{2k}{k} x^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-4x)^k \binom{-1/2}{k} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}$$ where the last equality is the [generalized binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem) in action.

Answer (score 3):

The sum is a convolution of the sequence $a_n = \binom{2n}{n}$ with itself. This suggests generating functions. Multiplying generating functions for two sequences results in a generating function for the convolution of the two sequences:

If $f(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n x^n$ and $g(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} b_n x^n$, then $$f(x)g(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \left(\sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}\right) x^n$$

The generating function $f$ for the sequence $\binom{2n}{n}$ is given by $$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 4x}}$$

Since $[f(x)]^2 = \frac{1}{1-4x}$, which is the generating function for $4^n$, the given sum is $4^n$.

There are approaches that don't involve generating functions, but the generating function calculation is very quick.