# Proving $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}=\sum_{n\geq0}{2n\choose n}x^n$

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}=\sum_{n\geq0}{2n\choose n}x^n$$

Can someone give me a hint on how to start with this problem?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}=(1-4x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

Then use the binomial theorem,

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}=\sum_{n\geq0}{-\frac{1}{2}\choose n}(-4x)^n$$

Answer (score 4):

There are at least a couple of ways. The easiest is probably the one already given by herpderp. Another is to start from the identity

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2k}k\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}=2^{2n}=4^n\;;$$

this is far from trivial, but there is a combinatorial proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/72661/12042) and another one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/360780/12042). On the other hand,

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2k}k\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}$$

is the coefficient of $x^n$ in

$$\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{2n}nx^n\right)^2\;,$$

so

$$\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{2n}nx^n\right)^2=\sum_{n\ge 0}4^nx^n\;,$$

and from there the result is very easy.