# Proving an Identity involving $4^N$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I am trying to prove the following identity:

$$\sum_{k=0}^N\left({2 \, N - 2 \, k \choose N - k}{2 \, k \choose k}\right)=4^N$$

I have tried writing $4^N=2^{2N}=(1+1)^{2N}=(1+1)^N(1+1)^N$, and expanding each of these as a binomial expansion, but I have found nothing but dead ends so far. Any ideas?

I am currently working through a Ch. 3 "Generating Functions" from  Analysis of Algorithms by Sedgewick/Flajolet. This is problem #30.

Thanks.

Comment: You could try Herbert Wilf's Snake Oil Method [here](http://www.imocompendium.com/database/index.php?options=357&lmm=0)

Comment: You’ll find both combinatorial and non-combinatorial proofs [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72367/proof-of-a-combinatorial-identity-sum-i-0n-2i-choose-i2n-i-choose-n) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37971/identity-for-convolution-of-central-binomial-coefficients).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let, $f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2n \choose n}x^n=(1-4x)^{-1/2}$. Then your LHS will be coefficient of $x^N$ of $f^2(x)=(1-4x)^{-1}$ which is $4^N$=RHS.

Answer (score 1):

Start off by noting
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{N}\binom{2N-2k}{N-k}\binom{2k}{k}=[x^{N}]\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k}x^{k}\right)^2.
$$
Now, what's inside the square is the OGF for the central binomial coefficients; you may have seen it before.  It happens that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k}x^k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}.
$$
So, we find that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{N}\binom{2N-2k}{N-k}\binom{2k}{k}=[x^N]\frac{1}{1-4x}=[x^N]\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(4x)^k=4^N,
$$
as claimed.

Answer (score 1):

Starting 
$$\tag 1\binom {n}{k}\binom{n-1/2}{k}=\binom{2n}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}/2^{2k}$$
In particular:

$$ \tag 2 \binom{-1/2}{k}=\bigg (\frac {-1}{4}\bigg)  ^k\binom{2k}{k}$$

Now consider following Vandermonde's identity:

$$\sum\limits_{k}\binom{-1/2}{k}\binom{-1/2}{n-k}=\binom{-1}{n}=(-1)^n$$

Inserting $(2)$ and remove summing

$$\tag3 \binom{-1/2}{k}\binom{-1/2}{n-k}=\bigg (\frac {-1}{4}\bigg)  ^k\binom{2k}{k}\bigg 
(\frac {-1}{4}\bigg)  ^{n-k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}=\bigg (\frac {-1}{4}\bigg)^n\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}$$

Finally summing again:

$$\sum\limits_{k}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}=4^n$$