# Combinatorial proof of $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{2k}{k} \binom{2n-2k}{n-k} =4^n$

Tags: combinatorics

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2k}{k} \binom{2n-2k}{n-k} = 4^n$$

Is there a combinatorial proof of above identity, without any arithmetic transformation?
 
Thanks...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72367/proof-of-a-combinatorial-identity-sum-i-0n-2i-choose-i2n-i-choose-n?lq=1