# Sum of a product with 2 binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

What is the value of the folowing sum and why: $$\sum_{n=0}^k\binom{2n}{n}\cdot\binom{2(k-n)}{k-n}$$

Comment: Probably helps to use "Gauss summation" here. Write the series as $\sum a_n$ and pair terms $a_n$ and $a_{k-n}$.

Comment: There is a (difficult) combinatorial proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72367/proof-of-a-combinatorial-identity-sum-limits-i-0n-2i-choose-i2n-i-ch/72661#72661) and a couple more proofs, one combinatorial, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37971/identity-for-convolution-of-central-binomial-coefficients-sum-limits-k-0n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{k \ge 0} \left(\sum_{n=0}^k a_n b_{k-n}\right) z^k= \left(\sum_{k\ge 0} a_k z^k\right)\left(\sum_{k\ge 0} b_k z^k\right)$$
Take $a_n=b_n=\binom{2n}{n}$ to obtain
\begin{align}
\sum_{k \ge 0} \left(\sum_{n=0}^k \binom{2n}{n} \binom{2(k-n)}{k-n}\right) z^k
&= \left(\sum_{k\ge 0} \binom{2k}{k} z^k\right)\left(\sum_{k\ge 0} \binom{2k}{k} z^k\right) \\
&= \left(\sum_{k\ge 0} \binom{2k}{k}z^k\right)^2 \\
&= \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\right)^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{1-4z} \\
&= \sum_{k \ge 0} (4z)^k \\
&= \sum_{k \ge 0} 4^k z^k,
\end{align}
so
$$\sum_{n=0}^k \binom{2n}{n} \binom{2(k-n)}{k-n} = 4^k.$$

Comment: Downvoting a perfectly good answer is misleading, which in my view makes it vandalism.

Comment: Agree. It is kind of sad to see -1 when I read the solution. Don't know what kind of person did it. Sick!