# what is the easiest way   to represent $ \sqrt{1 + x} $ in series

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

How to expand $ \sqrt{1 + x}$.
$$ \sum_{n = 0}^\infty {{\left ( 1 \over 2\right )!}x^n \over n! \left({1 \over 2 }- n\right )!} = 1 + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty {{\left ( 1 \over 2\right )!}x^n \over n! \left({1 \over 2 }- n\right )!}$$
How can I simplify $ \left({1 \over 2 }- n\right )! $?

Comment: [A related thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69270).

Comment: yeah ... i know that, but can I manipulate those things around to prove that they are equivalent?

Comment: thanks ... i think i should try it.

Comment: Well, you're not supposed to expand out $\binom{1/2}{n}$ as factorials in this case, if you're not willing to use the formulae in my answer in the question I linked to. See Byron's approach there.

Comment: no .... i'll stick with yours.

Comment: For reference: $$(-4)^n(1-2n)\binom{1/2}{n}=(-4)^n\binom{-1/2}{n}=\binom{2n}{n}$$

Comment: thanks .... i'll try. if you like ... you can post hint as an answer!!

Comment: @J.M. can i use $ (1/2 - n)! = (-1)^n (n - 1/2)!$

Comment: they seem to have inverse relation

Comment: Oops, that isn't the correct relation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per OP's request:

One way to deal with the binomial coefficients in your series would be to use the [duplication formula for the factorial](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5.E5):

$$\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{4^n}{\sqrt \pi}\frac{\left(n-\frac12\right)!}{n!}$$

and the [reflection formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5.E3)

$$\left(-n-\frac12\right)!\left(n-\frac12\right)!=(-1)^n\pi$$

The other way is to use the following *definition*, valid for any *complex* $x$:

$$\binom{x}{n}=\frac1{n!}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x-k)$$

Comment: is it [this relation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F2+-+n%29!+%3D+%28-1%29^%28n%2B1%29+pi%2F%28n-3%2F2%29!)

Answer (score 4):

Just to motivate a more elementary solution.

Let $$f(x)=\sqrt{x+1}=(x+1)^{1/2}$$

Now, we expand around $x=0$.

$$f'(x)=\frac 1 2 (x+1)^{1/2-1}$$

$$f''(x)=\frac 1 2 \left(\frac 1 2-1 \right)(x+1)^{1/2-2}$$

$$f'''(x)=\frac 1 2 \left(\frac 1 2-1 \right)\left(\frac 1 2-2 \right)(x+1)^{1/2-3}$$

By induction, we get

$$f^{(n)}(x)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(\frac 1 2 -k\right)(x+1)^{1/2-n}$$

Thus, we get

$$f^{(n)}(0)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(\frac 1 2 -k\right)$$

$$f^{(n)}(0)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(\frac {1 -2k}{2}\right)$$

$$f^{(n)}(0)=(-1)^{n}\frac{1}{2^{n}}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \left({2k-1}\right)$$

Now, note the product is exclusively of odd factors up to $(2n-3)$. What we do is fill in the missing even  numbers, and divide to keep things the same. Note that $(2n-2)\cdots 4\cdot 2=2^{n-1} (n-1)!$

$${f^{(n)}}(0) = {( - 1)^n}\frac{1}{{{2^n}{2^{n - 1}}(n - 1)!}}\prod\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {\left( {2k} \right)} \prod\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\left( {2k - 1} \right)} $$

$${f^{(n)}}(0) = \frac{{{{( - 1)}^n}}}{{{2^n}{2^{n - 1}}(n - 1)!}}\prod\limits_{k = 1}^{2n - 2} k  = {( - 1)^n}\frac{1}{{{2^{2n - 1}}}}\frac{{\left( {2n - 2} \right)!}}{{\left( {n - 1} \right)!}}$$

Thus, we have that

$$\sqrt {1 + x}  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{{( - 1)}^n}}}{{{2^{2n - 1}}}}} \frac{{\left( {2n - 2} \right)!}}{{n!\left( {n - 1} \right)!}}{x^n}$$

$$\sqrt {1 + x}  = 1 + \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{{( - 1)}^n}}}{{{2^{2n - 2}}}}} \frac{{\left( {2n - 2} \right)!}}{{\left( {n - 1} \right)!\left( {n - 1} \right)!}}\frac{{{x^n}}}{n}$$

$$\sqrt {1 + x}  = 1 + \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{{( - 1)}^n}}}{{{2^{2n}}}}} \frac{{\left( {2n} \right)!}}{{n!n!}}\frac{{{x^{n + 1}}}}{{n + 1}}$$

$$\sqrt {1 + x}  = 1 + \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{{( - 1)}^{n + 1}}}}{{{2^{2n + 1}}}}} {2n\choose n}\frac{{{x^{n + 1}}}}{{n + 1}}$$

Note this gives that

$$\frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 + x} }} = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{{( - 1)}^{n + 1}}}}{{{2^{2n}}}}} {2n\choose n}{x^n}$$

Comment: thanks ... looks like i've been making mistake!!

Comment: You derived the one for the reciprocal...

Comment: strange ... $ 1 \over \sqrt 2 $ [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum[%28-1%29^n+%282+n%29!%2F%28%28n!%29^2+4^n%29%2C+{n%2C+0%2C+Infinity}]) nevertheless helpful. Could you modify a bit ... so that it's helpful to remember.