# Simple Random Walk

Tags: probability, limits, binomial-coefficients

How to find:

$\lim\limits_{N \to \infty}\sum\limits_{m=0}^Nu_m$ where $u_m$=${2m \choose m}p^mq^m$

I know there are two cases to consider depending if $p$ and $q$ are equal or not. I should probably mention p and q are probabilities related to a simple random walk. I suspect the infinite sum is bounded for an asymmetric walk and unbounded for a symmetric walk but I'm struggling to come up with a closed form, ive tried relating it to the $(1+pq)^a$ expansion for some $a$ but I can't seem to progress.

Thanks

Comment: Sure about the *square* of the binomial coefficient?

Comment: @Did sorry I dont understand what you mean.

Comment: You've got the same binomial coefficient both in the sum and in definition of $u_m$; Did was asking whether it is intentional or a typo.

Comment: @PeterKošinár yes its a typo

Comment: @Did ive corrected my post, it indeed was a typo.

Comment: This should help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69270/show-sum-limits-n-0-infty2n-choose-nxn-1-4x-1-2

Comment: @ByronSchmuland thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Byron indicated, for every $p\ne\frac12$ in $[0,1]$,
$$
\sum_{m=0}^\infty{2m\choose m}(pq)^m=\frac1{\sqrt{1-4pq}}=\frac1{|p-q|}.$$