# Conjecture: $\sum\limits_{n\geq0}\left(\frac12\right)^n\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2n-2k+1}{2n-2k+2}=\sqrt2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, closed-form

I am trying to solve a problem I made form myself: proving that 
$$\sum_{n\geq0}\left(\frac12\right)^n\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2n-2k+1}{2n-2k+2}=\sqrt2$$
The highly accurate powers of [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kmrkmvfook) seem to confirm my hunch. But how do I prove it?

I was just messing around with products and generating functions, and then I noticed that the numerical value of the sum in question was suspiciously similar to $\sqrt2$, so I conjectured the result. Unfortunately I found this completely by accident and have absolutely no idea of how to prove it.

Feeble attempt:

Define $$S(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}x^n\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2n-2k+1}{2n-2k+2}$$
Which Wolfram says is equal to $$S(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}x^n\frac{(1/2-n)_n}{(-n)_n}$$
With $\displaystyle (x)_n=\frac{\Gamma(x+n)}{\Gamma(x)}$. But that doesn't really make sense because $\Gamma(0)$ is undefined. So all in all I'm just confused.

Could I have some help?

---

Edit:

According to the comments, it suffices to prove that 
$$\sum_{n\geq1}\left(\frac12\right)^n\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2n-2k+1}{2n-2k+2}=\sqrt2-1$$

Comment: Satisfy yourself that $(0)_0=1$.

Comment: @J.G. I am now satisfied

Comment: In case of $n=0$, product in your sum is empty product, so you may regard it as 1. (Or just do the sum for $n\geq1$)

Comment: I don't think you need to include the $n=0$ case because the product is not defined for it.

Comment: @Antinous For $n=0$ the product is empty, and thus conventionally defined to equal $1$

Comment: @Learner I didn't know that. Excluding $n=0$ gives a different answer, so as you say $n=0$ is still required to include the initial additive $1$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The products can be rewritten as 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} \frac{1}{2^n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} \frac{1}{8^n}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now use
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \binom{2n}{n} x^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Edit:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2n-2k+1}{2n-2k+2}&=&\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k-1}{2k} =\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\\
&=&\frac{(2n)!}{(2^n n!)^2}=\binom{2n}{n} \frac{1}{2^{2n}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Woah seriously?? (+1) That was fast! By the way, could you include the proof for your magical rewriting of products?

Comment: Wait actually no: I'm not gonna accept your answer until you show in detail how $$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2n-2k+1}{2n-2k+2}=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}=\frac1{2^{2n}}{2n\choose n}$$

Comment: Sure ... give me a few mins ?

Comment: Very nice. Thank you!

Comment: To add some kind of reference for the result on $\binom{2n}n$, I'll mention links some other posts on this site: [Generating functions and central binomial coefficient](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1064216) and [Show $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{2n \choose n}x^n=(1-4x)^{-1/2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/69270). (And probably more posts about this can be found.)

Answer (score 2):

Another way is
$$
\eqalign{
  & \prod\limits_{k = 1}^n {{{2n - 2k + 1} \over {2n - 2k + 2}}}  = \prod\limits_{k = 1}^n {{{\left( {n - k} \right) + 1/2} \over {\left( {n - k} \right) + 1}}}
  = \prod\limits_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {{{j + 1/2} \over {j + 1}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( {1/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,n\,} } } \over {n!}}
 = {{\Gamma \left( {n + 1/2} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {1/2} \right)\Gamma \left( {n + 1} \right)}} =
  \left( \matrix{ n - 1/2 \cr   n \cr}  \right)
 = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} \left( \matrix{   - 1/2 \cr   n \cr}  \right) \cr} 
$$
and then apply the binomial expansion.

Comment: Neat! thank you!