# Using the Taylor expansion for ${(1+x)}^{-1/2}$, evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n} a^n$

Tags: real-analysis, binomial-coefficients, taylor-expansion

Using the Taylor expansion for $${(1+x)}^{-1/2}$$ we have $${(1+x)}^{-1/2}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-1/2}{n} (x^n)$$
for $|x|<1$.

But if $|a| <1$, how can we use the above fact to find

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n} a^n?$$

Thanks! Help much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: ${-\frac{1}{2}\choose n} = (-\frac{1}{4})^n {2n \choose n}$

Comment: A part of [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30343/help-with-summing-a-power-series/30407#30407) is devoted to an answer.

Comment: You may not quite have the right expansion. But when you get the right one, observe that for example $(-1/2)(-3/2)(-5/2)(-7/2)=(-1)^4(1/2)^4 (8!)/(2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot 8)$. After some simplification this is $(-1)^4(1/2^4)(1/2^4)(8!)/4!$. For the coefficient of $x^4$ in the expansion of the right thing, there is another factor of $4!$ at the bottom.

Comment: Please note that you did not give the expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}$, but of $(1+x)^{-1/2}$. If you want to **start** from the expansion of $(1+x)^{1/2}$, which is what you wrote except it is $\binom{1/2}{n}$, **not** $\binom{-1/2}{n}$, first differentiate term by term to get the expansion of $(1/2)x^{-1/2}$, then multiply both sides by $2$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Write out what $\binom{-1/2}{n}$ means; i.e., 
$$
\begin{align}
\binom{-1/2}{n} &= \frac{(-1/2)(-3/2) \cdots ((-2n+1)/2)}{n!} = \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n} \frac{(1)(3) \cdots (2n-1)}{n!} \\
&= \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n} \frac{(2n)!}{2(4) \cdots (2n)n!} = \left(\frac{-1}{4}\right)^n \frac{(2n)!}{n!n!} \\
&= \left(\frac{-1}{4}\right)^n \binom{2n}{n}.
\end{align}
$$
This should be enough for you to be able to find $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} a^n$.

---

Are you sure you mean $\sqrt{1+x}$, though?  That would give $\sqrt{1+x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/2}{n} x^n$.  Then, following through the same argument as above you would obtain $\binom{1/2}{n} = \frac{-1}{2n-1} \left(\frac{-1}{4}\right)^n \binom{2n}{n}$, which would be a bit more difficult to deal with because of the $2n-1$ in the denominator.

Comment: It looks like others posted basically the same thing in the comments while I was typing my answer!  Still, I'll leave this up so that the question has an actual answer.

Comment: You're right! It was (1+x)^(-1/2). Thanks so much for the help! I'll edit the post to reflect changes, to help others find this problem.