# summation of infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Find$$S=1+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{18}+\frac{7}{324}+\cdots\infty$$

I could figure this pattern for denominators: $t_k=3t_{k-1}t_{k-2}$ but not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I see you used the geometry tag. Did this series arise in a geometric context (by which one could hopefully anticipate the next term)?

Comment: And how is the numerator going?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try for [Newton's generalised binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem) with $x=1$

So, we have $\displaystyle ry=\frac16\ \ \ \ (1)$ and $\displaystyle\frac{r(r-1)}{2!}y^2=\frac1{18}\  \ \ \ (2)$

Squaring $(1)$ and dividing by $(2)$ we get $\displaystyle r=-\frac13$ and consequently  $\displaystyle y=-\frac12$

which satisfies $$\frac{r(r-1)(r-2)}{3!}y^3=\frac7{324}$$

So, the sum will be $$\left[1+\left(-\frac12\right)\right]^{-\frac13}$$

Comment: thats cool, thanks

Comment: @Sawarnik, How about this?

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma, My Pleasure. See also, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746388/calculating-1-frac13-frac1-cdot33-cdot6-frac1-cdot3-cdot53-cdot6-cdot/746975#746975