# $1 + \frac34 + \frac34.\frac58 + \frac34.\frac58.\frac7{12} + ....... = ?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the value of the following infinite sum:
$$1 + \frac34 + \frac34.\frac58 + \frac34.\frac58.\frac7{12} + .......$$

---

I need a definitive hint, please help.

Comment: WolframAlpha says $2\sqrt{2}$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%2B+sum+from+n%3D1+to+infinity+of+%28product+from+k%3D1+to+n+of+%281%2B2k%29%2F%284k%29%29

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746388/calculating-1-frac13-frac1-cdot33-cdot6-frac1-cdot3-cdot53-cdot6-cdot/746975#746975

Comment: This is a [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).