# Sum $\frac{1}{6} + \frac{5}{6\cdot 12} + \frac{5\cdot 8}{6\cdot 12\cdot 18} + \frac{5\cdot 8\cdot 11}{6\cdot 12\cdot 18\cdot 24}+\ldots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

A series is given as follows

$$\frac{1}{6} + \frac{5}{6\cdot 12} + \frac{5\cdot 8}{6\cdot 12\cdot 18} + \frac{5\cdot 8\cdot 11}{6\cdot 12\cdot 18\cdot 24}+\ldots$$

Can you give me hints to get started finding its value? Thanks.

Comment: 6.12.18, are you sure?

Comment: Can you please edit your thread to use LaTeX? It will make things much clearer.

Comment: It would be nice if you would properly format your question.

Comment: I just did some formatting to make the question readable, but Baby Dragon is right. Some terms have more than one decimal place. Can you clarify what these terms are?

Comment: I think the intent is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\prod_{i=0}^{n-2} 5+3i}{\prod_{i=1}^n 6i}$, where my convention is that the empty product $\prod_{i=0}^{-1} a_i$ is $1$.

Comment: I think that this @Ian is correct. I think that we should wait for the OP to tell us what is meant. I looked at the account of the OP and some of the questions and answers were incongruent with the type of mistake I attributed.

Comment: @SujaanKunalan dots mewns numbers are multoplied here

Comment: Sum is very-very close to this value: $$\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{4}-1}{2} \approx 0.2937005259840997...$$ Perhaps, it is exact sum of the series.

Comment: @Oleg567 how did you do this

Comment: @SophieClad, evaluated numerical value, and then used http://oldweb.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html (Inverse Symbolic Calculator) to know possible closed form of the value.

Comment: I edited the question to make it a better question. It still could be a duplicate though.

Comment: You can recognize this series as a Taylor series for $\frac12(x+1)^{-2/3}-\frac12$ evaluated at $x=-{\frac12}$. The general way to handle this kind of series is to (1) recognize that the denominator has $n!$ that can be factored out, which is part of the taylor formula, and (2) recognize the numerator's factors increase by $3$. So with appropriate manipulation, you can find a series for a function of the form $(1+x)^{k/3}$ and an $x$-value that almost gives you your series. (There is also a scaling factor and an accounting of the constant term to work out.)

Comment: @alex.jordan plz elaborate ur approach

Comment: @SophieClad, See also, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746388/calculating-1-frac13-frac1-cdot33-cdot6-frac1-cdot3-cdot53-cdot6-cdot/746396#746396

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^n=1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2+...$
Multiplying the series term by term by $2$

On comparing, $nx=\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2=\frac{5}{3.12}$

Solving for $n,x$ we get $n=\frac{-2}{3},x=\frac{-1}{2}$

So the sum becomes $\{(\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{-2}{3}}-1\}=2^\frac{2}{3}-1=4^\frac{1}{3}-1$

since $2$ has been multiplied before divide the result by $2$

Comment: thanks for answer , but answer is what as stated by oleg567 in comment

Comment: @SophieClad check if this suits you

Comment: @Learnmore why did you start by multiplying by 2. The answer is completely different if I don't multiply by 2.

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac12\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{3i-1}{6i}
&=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{2^nn!}\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{3i-1}{3}\\
&=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{(-2)^nn!}\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{1-3i}{3}\\
&=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{(-2)^nn!}\prod_{i=1}^n\left(\frac13-i\right)\\
&=\left[\frac12\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}\prod_{i=1}^n\left(\frac13-i\right)\right]_{x=-1/2}\\
\end{align}$$

Now note that for $n\geq1$, $\prod_{i=1}^n\left(\frac13-i\right)=f^{(n)}(0)$, where $f(x)=(x+1)^{-2/3}$. We can manipulate the expression a little further to see it as a Taylor series for $f$.

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac12\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{3i-1}{6i}
&=\left[\frac12\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}\prod_{i=1}^n\left(\frac13-i\right)-\frac12\right]_{x=-1/2}\\
&=\left[\frac12\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}f^{(n)}(0)\right]_{x=-1/2}-\frac12\\
&=\frac12f(-1/2)-\frac12\\
&=\frac12(1/2)^{-2/3}-\frac12\\
&=\sqrt[3]{1/2}-\frac12\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

For any $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ we have
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{n}(3k+2) = \frac{3^n\,\Gamma\left(n+\frac{5}{3}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)}\tag{1}$$
and the value of the RHS at $n=0$ equals $1$. It follows that the whole series can be represented as

$$ S=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{6^{n+1}(n+1)!}\cdot\frac{3^n\,\Gamma\left(n+\frac{5}{3}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{6\cdot 2^n}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{5}{3}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)\Gamma(n+2)}\tag{2} $$
or, by using [Euler's beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and the [reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the $\Gamma$ function, as
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{6\,\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)}\cdot\frac{B\left(n+\frac{5}{3},\frac{1}{3}\right)}{2^n}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{8\pi}\sum_{n\geq 0}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n+2/3}(1-x)^{-2/3}}{2^n}\,dx \tag{3}$$
from which:
$$ S = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2/3}}{(1-x)^{2/3}(2-x)}\,dx \stackrel{\frac{x}{1-x}\mapsto z}{=}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^{2/3}}{(1+z)(2+z)}\tag{4}$$
and:
$$ S = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4\pi}\left(-\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^{2/3}}{z(1+z)}\,dz+2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^{2/3}}{z(2+z)}\,dz\right).\tag{5} $$
Euler's beta function then leads to:
$$ S = \color{blue}{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}-\frac{1}{2}} \approx 0.2937.\tag{6}$$

Comment: please explain me  how can we write $\displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^{n}(3k+2) = \frac{3^n\,\Gamma\left(n+\frac{5}{3}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)}$.

Comment: @DurgeshTiwari: by just exploiting the main functional identity for the $\Gamma$ function: $$\Gamma(n+5/3)=(n+2/3)\Gamma(n+2/3)=(n+2/3)(n-1/3)\Gamma(n-1/3)=\ldots$$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&{1 \over 6} + {5 \over 6 \cdot 12} + {5 \cdot 8 \over 6 \cdot 12 \cdot 18} + {5 \cdot 8 \cdot 11 \over 6\cdot 12\cdot 18\cdot 24} + \cdots =
{1 \over 6} + \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\prod_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{3k + 5} \over \prod_{k = 0}^{n + 1}\pars{6k + 6}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 6} + \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{3^{n + 1}\prod_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{k + 5/3} \over 6^{n + 2}\prod_{k = 0}^{n + 1}\pars{k + 1}} =
{1 \over 6} + {1 \over 6}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over 2^{n + 1}}\,{\pars{5/3}^{\overline{n + 1}} \over \pars{n + 2}!}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 6} + {1 \over 6}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over 2^{n + 1}}\,
{\Gamma\pars{n + 8/3}/\Gamma\pars{5/3} \over \pars{n + 2}!} =
{1 \over 6} + {1 \over 6}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over 2^{n + 1}}\,
{\pars{n + 5/3}! \over \pars{2/3}!\pars{n + 2}!}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 6} + {1 \over 6}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over 2^{n + 1}}
{n + 8/3 \choose n + 2}{1 \over n + 8/3} =
{1 \over 6} + {1 \over 6}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over 2^{n + 1}}
{-5/3 \choose n + 2}\pars{-1}^{n + 2}\,{1 \over n + 8/3}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 6} + {1 \over 6}\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}{1 \over 2^{n - 1}}
{-5/3 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}\,{1 \over n + 2/3} =
{1 \over 6} + {1 \over 6}\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over 2^{n - 1}}
{-5/3 \choose n}\int_{0}^{1}x^{n - 1/3}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 6} + {1 \over 3}\int_{0}^{1}
\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}{-5/3 \choose n}\pars{-\,{x \over 2}}^{n}
\,{\dd x \over x^{1/3}}
=
{1 \over 6} + {1 \over 3}\ \underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}
\bracks{\pars{1 - {x \over 2}}^{-5/3} - 1 - {5 \over 3}\,{x \over 2}}
\,{\dd x \over x^{1/3}}}_{\ds{-2 + {3 \over 2^{1/3}}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{{1 \over 2^{1/3}} - {1 \over 2}} \approx 0.2937
\end{align}