# is multinomial expansion required to solve this infinite sum?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I cannot solve this infinite series by any means using polynomial ascending power expansions...

$$1+\sum_{i=1}^\infty(1/2)^i \prod_{k=1}^i\frac{3k-1}{3k}$$
Could somebody help me?

Comment: @Mr. Chip Thanks for editing

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2342250/evaluate-1-frac26-frac2-cdot-56-cdot-12-frac2-cdot-5-cdot-86-cd

Comment: @Jean Marie I got no idea, maybe i need calculus, please help me to go through it

Comment: @Robert Z can you assure that is the same problem? I want to confirm it once more

Comment: @pandong Your work: compare the problems and see the similarities!

Comment: @Jean Marie sorry editing

Comment: @ Thanks everybody, it was a typing error from my end...i am sorry