# Find the sum of the following infinite series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Find the sum of the following infinite series in which numerator and denominator contains term which are product of integers in arithmetic progression:

> > $$\frac15+ \frac{1\times4}{5\times10}+\frac{1\times4\times7}{5\times10\times15}+\dots$$

I found this problem in an Indian competitive exam. I tried some conventional methods, but could not find the sum. Please offer any help you think is useful. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the [Generalized Binomial Theorem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem)?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936146

Comment: Uh, any plans to at least comment on or vote on the answers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\frac {1}{5}-\frac{1.4}{5.10}+\frac{1.4.7}{5.10.15}-\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036288/frac-15-frac1-45-10-frac1-4-75-10-15-cdot-cdot-cdot-cdot-cdot-c) - at least [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036288/frac-15-frac1-45-10-frac1-4-75-10-15-cdot-cdot-cdot-cdot-cdot-c/1036313#1036313) covers it.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the series expansion for $f(x)=(1-x)^{-1/3}$:

$$\begin{align}f(x) &= 1+\frac13 x + \frac1{2!} \left ( -\frac13\right ) \left ( -\frac{4}{3}\right ) x^2 - \frac1{3!} \left ( -\frac13\right ) \left ( -\frac{4}{3}\right )\left ( -\frac{7}{3}\right ) x^3 +\cdots\\ &= 1+\frac13 x + \frac{1 \cdot 4}{2! 3^2} x^2 + \frac{1 \cdot 4 \cdot 7}{3! 3^3} x^2+\cdots\end{align}$$

Thus, the stated sum is simply

$$f \left ( \frac{3}{5} \right ) - 1 = \left ( \frac{5}{2} \right )^{1/3}-1$$

Answer (score 0):

Can be solved by looking here:
[$\frac {1}{5}-\frac{1.4}{5.10}+\frac{1.4.7}{5.10.15}-\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036288/frac-15-frac1-45-10-frac1-4-75-10-15-cdot-cdot-cdot-cdot-cdot-c/1036313#1036313)

The sign change in the terms
is covered by my answer.