# Series with $n$th term having integer raised to the power of $n$ in the denominator

Tags: sequences-and-series

> $$
> 1+\frac{4}{6}+\frac{4\cdot5}{6\cdot9}+\frac{4\cdot5\cdot6}{6\cdot9\cdot12}+\cdots
> $$

I could reduce it to $n$th term being $\dfrac{(n+1)\cdot(n+2)}{n!\cdot3^n}$. 
Took me an hour just to get to this.
But  I am now stuck up. PL. Help

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746388/calculating-1-frac13-frac1-cdot33-cdot6-frac1-cdot3-cdot53-cdot6-cdot

Comment: The $n$th term $$=\frac{4\cdot5\cdot6\cdots(n+3)}{6\cdot9\cdot12\cdots(3n+3)},$$ right?

Comment: Have corrected nth term in the question.

Comment: It's incorrect, we don't need it particularly though  if you follow the linked answers.

Comment: Any other method ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$1+\frac{4}{6}+\frac{4\cdot5}{6\cdot9}+\frac{4\cdot5\cdot6}{6\cdot9\cdot12}+\cdots$$
$$=1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n+3)!}{2\times3\times3^n\times(n+1)!}$$
$$=1+\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n+2)\times(n+3)}{3^{n+1}}$$

By induction, we can show that for $n\ge7$, $0<\frac{(n+2)\times(n+3)}{3^{n+1}}<\frac{1}{n^2}$, and hence the series is convergent.

[In fact](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20n%3D1%20to%20infinity%20%28n%2B2%29%28n%2B3%29%2F%283%5E%28n%2B1%29%29), $=1+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{11}{4}=\frac{19}{8}$