# Help with taylor series summation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

$f(x) = \sqrt{x}$

When you do expansion, you get the following:

$$4 + \frac{x-16}{2^3}\times 1! + \frac{(x-16)^2}{2^8}\times 2! + \frac{3(x-16)^3}{2^{13}}\times 3!$$$$+ \frac{15(x-16)^4}{2^{18}}\times 4! + \frac{105(x-16)^5}{2^{23}}\times 5!+\cdots$$

I know the denominator of the summation with E n=1 -> infinity is 2^(5n-2) * n!.

But for the numerator it starts with $c_1 = 0$, $c_2 = 0$, $c_3 = 3$, $c_4 = 15$, $c_5 = 105$ as the coefficients on the $(x-16)^n$. What would be the coefficient in the summation for $(x-16)^n$, as in, what would $(x-16)^n$ multiply by in the numerator of the summation?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746388/calculating-1-frac13-frac1-cdot33-cdot6-frac1-cdot3-cdot53-cdot6-cdot  to get $$4\left(1+\dfrac{x-16}{16}\right)^{1/2}$$

Comment: @Ben Welcome to Maths SE.  __2__ things: I have reformatted your post but the input interpretation may be wrong so in future use
 [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1) to learn how to format via $\LaTeX$ and secondly, 
if someone gives an answer that is useful to you don't forget to tick it. All the best.