# Sum of the unknown power series

Tags: summation, power-series, taylor-expansion

I have the following series where $h$ and   $f$ are some functions. 
$$1+\frac{2}{5}fh^2+\frac{4}{21}f^2h^4+...,$$
which I figured can be written as
$$3\sum_{k=0} \frac{(2fh^2)^k}{4^{k+1}-1}.$$
I need help with this series. Does is it look like something specific ? Maybe it is some Taylor expansion or known series ?

Comment: You get in the sum for $\;k=0\;:\;\;3\cdot\frac{(2f)^2}{4-1}=4f^2\;$ , so that can't be correct.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746388/calculating-1-frac13-frac1-cdot33-cdot6-frac1-cdot3-cdot53-cdot6-cdot

Comment: @DonAntonio sorry, edited the question

Comment: Could you provide more terms? Three terms doesn't seem like enough to make any conclusions

Comment: @Yuriy S other terms seem to match the second formula.

Comment: mathematica didn't digest that one

Answer (score 3):

It's not a solution, it's a hint (and too long for a clear comment).

Assume the convergence of the series, it's partly different here.

With $\displaystyle f(x):=\prod\limits_{k=0}^\infty\left(1+\frac{x}{4^k}\right)$ which has the functional equation $f(x)=(1+x)f(x/4)$ we get

$$-\frac{d}{dx}\ln f(-x)-\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum\limits_{v=0}^\infty \frac{1}{4^{v+1}-x}=\sum\limits_{v=0}^\infty \frac{1}{4^{v+1}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{4^{k(v+1)}}=$$

$$\hspace{4cm}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{4^{k+1}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{4^{(k+1)v}}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{4^{k+1}-1}$$

If you have a closed form for the above defined product for $f(x)$ then you will get a solution for your series.

Comment: thank you for your answer! Unfortunately $x$ in my case is rather complicated and it will be not feaseble to deal with the product .

Comment: Sorry, that I cannot help you more, but it's hard to understand, what you  like to do with $fh^2$ . There are no informations. As it's written in your post you have to calculate first $fh^2$ and then put the result into $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{4^{k+1}-1}$ or equivalent into $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{4^{k+1}-x}$.

Comment: yes thats what it is. I probably don't understand something. If, for example, $x=e^{-t^2}$ how do I proceed ?

Comment: Then you have e.g. the sum $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{e^{kt^2}(4^{k+1}-1)}$. Good convergence.