# The Formula to this Sequence Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the formula for following sequence?

$$\frac12 + \frac12 \cdot \frac34 + \frac12 \cdot \frac34 \cdot \frac56 + ... + \frac12 \cdot \frac34 \cdot \frac56 ... \frac{2n - 1}{2n}$$

This is a question from my Calculus class about sequences.

Comment: good homework question.

Comment: To be honest, this isn't question for homework. It is an examples to the finals.

Comment: I'm just saying provide context.

Comment: Does it converge?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746388/calculating-1-frac13-frac1-cdot33-cdot6-frac1-cdot3-cdot53-cdot6-cdot

Comment: Just to be clear - what is meant by the "formula" here? Do you need to find the closed form for the $n$th term of the sequence? Or maybe you need to tell if it converges for $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Please reopen this question, as it is slightly different (sum to $n$ terms) from the supposed duplicate (sum to infinity).

Answer (score 4):

$$ 
\begin{align} 
&\, 1\,\cdot\,3\,\cdot\,5\,\cdots\,(2n-1) = (2n-1)!! \,,\quad\, 2\,\cdot\,4\,\cdot\,6\,\cdots\,(2n) = (2n)!! \\[2mm] 
&\, S_{\small n} = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1\,\cdot\,3}{2\,\cdot\,4}+\frac{1\,\cdot\,3\,\cdot\,5}{2\,\cdot\,4\,\cdot\,6}+\,\cdots\,+\frac{1\,\cdot\,3\,\cdot\,5\,\cdots\,(2n-1)}{2\,\cdot\,4\,\cdot\,6\,\cdots\,(2n)} \\[6mm] 
&\, \color{red}{1+S_{\small n}} = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1\,\cdot\,3}{2\,\cdot\,4}+\frac{1\,\cdot\,3\,\cdot\,5}{2\,\cdot\,4\,\cdot\,6}+\,\cdots\,+\frac{1\,\cdot\,3\,\cdot\,5\,\cdots\,(2n-1)}{2\,\cdot\,4\,\cdot\,6\,\cdots\,(2n)} \\[3mm] 
&\, \qquad = \frac{1\,\cdot\,3}{2}+\frac{1\,\cdot\,3}{2\,\cdot\,4}+\frac{1\,\cdot\,3\,\cdot\,5}{2\,\cdot\,4\,\cdot\,6}+\,\cdots\,+\frac{1\,\cdot\,3\,\cdot\,5\,\cdots\,(2n-1)}{2\,\cdot\,4\,\cdot\,6\,\cdots\,(2n)} \\[3mm] 
&\, \qquad = \frac{1\,\cdot\,3\,\cdot\,5}{2\,\cdot\,4}+\frac{1\,\cdot\,3\,\cdot\,5}{2\,\cdot\,4\,\cdot\,6}+\,\cdots\,+\frac{1\,\cdot\,3\,\cdot\,5\,\cdots\,(2n-1)}{2\,\cdot\,4\,\cdot\,6\,\cdots\,(2n)} \\[3mm] 
&\, \qquad = \,\cdots\, = \frac{1\,\cdot\,3\,\cdot\,5\,\cdots\,(2n+1)}{2\,\cdot\,4\,\cdot\,6\,\cdots\,(2n)} = \color{red}{\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n)!!}} \,\Rightarrow\, S_{\small n}=\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n)!!}-1 \\[6mm] 
&\, 1+\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_{\small n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n)!!}\color{red}{\,\longrightarrow\,\infty} \qquad \{{\small\text{divergent}}\}
\end{align} 
$$

Answer (score 2):

You are dealing with
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}.\tag{1}$$
It is well-known that $\frac{1}{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi k}}$ as $k\to +\infty$, hence the associated series is divergent by the p-test. We may also notice that, by the extended binomial theorem,
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{x^k}{4^k}\binom{2k}{k} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}-1 \tag{2}$$
hence the RHS of $(1)$ is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the Taylor series (at $x=0$) of
$$ \frac{1}{1-x}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}-1 \right) = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{3/2}}-\frac{1}{1-x}\tag{3} $$
and by the extended binomial theorem (again):
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{4^k}\binom{2k}{k} = \color{red}{\frac{2n+1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}-1}.\tag{4} $$
Obviously $(4)$ can be proved through creative telescoping or probabilistic arguments, too. Interesting question.

Comment: Nice solution (+1, earlier).  It can be shown easily that $$\frac 1{4^k}\binom {2k}k=\frac {2k+1}{4^k}\binom {2k}k-\frac {2(k-1)+1}{4^{k-1}}\binom {2(k-1)}{k-1}$$ which when summed telescopes nicely to the result shown in $(4)$. (as this question has been marked duplicate, it is not possible to post a new answer to show this derivation in full)

Comment: @hypergeometric: of course. In terms of generating functions, we are just stating that the derivative of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$ is given by half the product between $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and the function itself, essentially. There also is a nice probabilistic argument for showing such telescopic property.

Comment: The second term of RHS (in the equation in my comment) reduces to $$\frac {2k}{4^k}\binom {2k}k$$.

Comment: How can we use Extended Binomial Theorem to prove (4)?

Comment: The EBT allows to easily compute the Taylor coefficients of both the LHS and the RHS of (3).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{3}{4}\cdot \frac{5}{6}\cdot ...\cdot \frac{2n-1}{2n}= \frac{(2n-1)!}{2^n n!}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $x=-1,n=-1/2$ then your series is $$nx+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}x^{2}+\cdots$$ which is the general binomial series for $(1+x)^{n}$ except for the missing first term $1$. It is known from theory of binomial series (see towards the end of [this blog post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2016/07/the-general-binomial-theorem-part-2.html)) that if $x=-1$ then the binomial series is convergent only when $n\geq 0$. Thus the given series diverges.