# Prove that $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdots \frac{2n-1}{2n} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}$ without induction

Tags: inequality, products

> Prove that $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdots \frac{2n-1}{2n} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}$

I know this can be easily proved by induction. But I am looking for another approach. How do I prove this without induction? 
Here this question exists - [How does one prove that $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdots \frac{2n-1}{2n}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119773/how-does-one-prove-that-frac12-cdot-frac34-cdots-frac2n-12n-leq). But the only one solution there uses induction. But I am looking for solution other than induction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one prove that $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdots \frac{2n-1}{2n}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}?$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119773/how-does-one-prove-that-frac12-cdot-frac34-cdots-frac2n-12n-leq)

Comment: @MyGlasses Nope... It is not asking to find a prove by induction .... The only answer there uses induction

Comment: Any general statement involving all natural numbers $n$ will at some level rely for proof on "induction" as an axiomatic principle that defines natural numbers.  Perhaps you should explain more fully your motive in asking for a proof "without induction".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If we consider
$$a_n = \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} = \frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{2k}\right)\tag{1}$$
we have:
$$ a_n^2 = \frac{1}{4}\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{4k^2}\right) = \frac{1}{4n}\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{4k(k-1)}\right)\tag{2} $$
hence:
$$ 4n a_n^2 \leq \exp\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{4k(k-1)} \leq \exp\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \tag{3}$$
and:
$$ a_n \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{4e^{-1/4}n}} \tag{4}$$
is a stronger inequality, since $4e^{-1/4}\approx 3+\frac{1}{9}$.
 No induction, just squaring and creative telescoping.

Comment: Wow, very nice! +1

Comment: Seems to hard to me :( :'(

Comment: @RezwanArefin V. Hard. This is my attempt, hope it at least has some truth in it. http://imgur.com/a/KioSR

Comment: @Cppg Your's are harder than this one :V :V

Comment: This is so elegant ! Thanks for providing answers of this quality. Cheers.

Comment: Very nice solution! (+1). Reminiscent of your other solution [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2122928/168053) but nice to see it in product form.