# Showing that $ \sum_{n=1}^{m} \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k-1}{2k} = \frac{2(m+1)\Gamma(m+\frac{3}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(m+2)}$

Tags: summation, products

I'm trying to show the following identity,

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{m} \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k-1}{2k} = \frac{2(m+1)\Gamma(m+\frac{3}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(m+2)}.$$

First, simplify the product within the sum,

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{\prod_{k=1}^n (2k-1)}{\prod_{k=1}^n (2k)} \\
  = \sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}}{2^n n!} \\ 
 = \sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2} $$

I'm not sure where to continue from here. I know the factorials will be rewritten as the Gamma function and I'm guessing the $\sqrt{\pi}$ will come from Stirling's approximation. Where should I go from here?

Comment: Idk how to follow but observe that $\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}=\binom{2n}{n}$. Probably it will be easier to show how to go from the RHS to the LHS. And observe too that $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt\pi$.

Comment: This is simply a Beta Function. Your RHS can be written in the form $\frac{2}{\pi} (m+2)B(m+3/2,1/2)$

Comment: The LHS can be expressed as $\sum_{n=1}^m {2n \choose n}4^{-n}$ or as $\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}$

Comment: ...and the RHS is equivalent to $\binom{m+1/2}{m}$

Comment: [Your problem is solved in this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2122202/the-formula-to-this-sequence-series)

Comment: Your proposed answer is $\color{#f00}{\mathsf{correct}}$ whenever the sum starts at $n = 0$. Because it starts at $n = 1$, you have to subtract $\color{#f00}{1}$ to your proposed result. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^{m}\prod_{k = 1}^{n}{2k - 1 \over 2k} & =
\sum_{n = 1}^{m}{\prod_{k = 1}^{n}\pars{k - 1/2} \over \prod_{k = 1}^{n}k} =
\sum_{n = 1}^{m}{\pars{1/2}^{\overline{n}} \over n!} =
\sum_{n = 1}^{m}{\Gamma\pars{1/2 + n}/\Gamma\pars{1/2} \over n!}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{n = 1}^{m}{\pars{n - 1/2}! \over n!\pars{-1/2}!} =
\sum_{n = 1}^{m}{n - 1/2 \choose n} =
\bracks{z^{m}}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}z^{\ell}
\bracks{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{n - 1/2 \choose n}\bracks{n \leq \ell}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{z^{m}}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{n - 1/2 \choose n}
\sum_{\ell = n}^{\infty}z^{\ell} =
\bracks{z^{m}}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{n - 1/2 \choose n}
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}z^{\ell + n}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{z^{m}}{1 \over 1 - z}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{n - 1/2 \choose n}z^{n} =
\bracks{z^{m}}{1 \over 1 - z}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{-1/2 \choose n}\pars{-z}^{n} \\[5mm] & =
\bracks{z^{m}}{1 \over 1 - z}\bracks{\pars{1 - z}^{-1/2} - 1} =
\bracks{z^{m}}\pars{1 - z}^{-3/2} - \bracks{z^{m}}\pars{1 - z}^{-1}
\\[5mm] & =
{-3/2 \choose m}\pars{-1}^{m} - 1 =
{m + 1/2 \choose m} - 1 =
{\pars{m + 1/2}! \over m!\pars{1/2}!} - 1
\\[5mm] & =
{\Gamma\pars{m + 3/2} \over \Gamma\pars{m + 1}\Gamma\pars{3/2}} - 1 =
{\Gamma\pars{m + 3/2} \over
\bracks{\Gamma\pars{m + 2}/\pars{m + 1}}\bracks{\Gamma\pars{1/2}/2}} - 1
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{{2\pars{m + 1}\Gamma\pars{m + 3/2} \over \root{\pi}\Gamma\pars{m + 2}} - 1}
\end{align}

Comment: Insolito y brillante. (+1). Espero que le vaya bien en estos tiempos dificiles para su pais.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel Thanks. Here, the situation is quite tense. Nobody really knows what's going to happen. I'm living in a relatively peaceful place and I don't have to go to the university everyday because I'm already retired.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that from the RHS we have

$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}\frac{2(m+1)\Gamma(m+3/2)}{\sqrt\pi\Gamma(m+2)}&=\frac{2\cancel{(m+1)}(m+1/2)\Gamma(m+1/2)}{\Gamma(1/2)\cancel{(m+1)}\Gamma(m+1)}\\&=\frac{2(m+1/2)^\underline {m+1}\cancel{\Gamma(1/2)}}{m!\,\cancel{\Gamma(1/2)}}\\&=\binom{m+1/2}{m}=\prod_{k=1}^m\frac{k+1/2}{k}\\&=\prod_{k=1}^m\frac{2k+1}{2k}=\frac{(2m+1)!!}{(2m)!!}\tag{1}\end{align}$$

And from the LHS we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{(2n)!}{((2n)!!)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\tag{2}$$

To show that $(1)$ is equivalent to $(2)$ we can do this

$$\Delta\left(\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n)!!}\right)=\frac{(2n+3)!!}{(2n+2)!!}-\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n)!!}=\left(\frac{2n+3}{2n+2}-1\right)\cdot\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n)!!}=\\=\frac1{2n+2}\cdot\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n)!!}=\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n+2)!!}$$

Then

$$\sum_{n=h}^{m-1}\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n+2)!!}=\sum_{n=h+1}^{m}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}=\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n)!!}\bigg|_h^m\tag{3}$$

And from $(2)$ and $(3)$ we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}=\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n)!!}\bigg|_0^m=\frac{(2m+1)!!}{(2m)!!}-1$$

But there is a difference of $1$!! I double-checked the difference [in Wolfram-Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*(m+%2B+1)*Gamma%5Bm+%2B+3%2F2%5D%2F(Sqrt%5BPi%5D+Gamma%5Bm+%2B+2%5D)%3D%3DSum%5BProduct%5B(2+k+-+1)%2F(2+k),+%7Bk,+1,+n%7D%5D,+%7Bn,+1,+m%7D%5D), so you have a typo in your exercise.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^m\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k-1}{2k}
&=\sum_{n=1}^m\binom{n-1/2}{n}\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^m(-1)^n\binom{-1/2}{n}\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^m(-1)^m\binom{-1}{m-n}\binom{-1/2}{n}\tag{3}\\
&=(-1)^m\binom{-3/2}{m}-1\tag{4}\\
&=\binom{m+1/2}{m}-1\tag{5}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma\left(m+\frac32\right)}{\Gamma(m+1)\Gamma\left(\frac32\right)}-1\tag{6}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma\left(m+\frac32\right)}{\frac1{m+1}\Gamma(m+2)\frac12\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)}-1\tag{7}\\
&=\frac{2(m+1)}{\sqrt\pi}\frac{\Gamma\left(m+\frac32\right)}{\Gamma(m+2)}-1\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: convert product to [Binomial Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)
$(2)$: convert to [Negative Binomial Coefficient](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217647)
$(3)$: rewrite $(-1)^n$
$(4)$: [Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)
$(5)$: convert from negative binomial coefficient
$(6)$: express binomial coefficient with [Gamma functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)
$(7)$: apply $x\Gamma(x)=\Gamma(x+1)$
$(8)$: $\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)=\sqrt\pi$

The sum would be as given in the question if the $n=0$ term were included in the sum.