# Show this infinite series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I want to show that the series $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k} (-1)^k$$ converges. I'm fairly sure it converges to zero, but haven't been successful. Will the ratio test work?

Comment: yes I think it will work.

Comment: WolframAlpha says the [ratio test is inconclusive](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+k+%3D+1+to+infty+((1%2F2+choose+k)+(-1)%5Ek)). It exceeds standard computation time if I try and [check it is equal to $0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+k+%3D+1+to+infty+((1%2F2+choose+k)+(-1)%5Ek)+%3D+0)

Answer (score 4):

The ratio test will fail. But the series is absolutely
convergent. The $k$-th term
is
$$-\frac{(1/2)(1/2)(3/2)\cdots(k-3/2)}{k!}.$$
This is $O(1/k^{3/2})$ by say Stirling formula, or that its logarithm is
a constant plus $\sum_{j=2}^k\ln(1-3/(2k))$.

By Abel's theorem, The sum is
$$\lim_{t\to 1^-}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\binom{1/2}k(-1)^kt^k$$
which is $-1$ since this function is $-1+\sqrt{1-t}$.

Comment: what the heck. is that how fractional factorials work??

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Can you explicitly use the Stirling formula to justify the order of $1/k^{3/2}$?

Comment: @Elliot To use Stirling, you express $\binom{1/2}k$ in terms of factorials and the expression $1\times 3\times 5\times\cdots (2k-3)$. But that is $(2k-2)!/((k-1)!2^k)$ so that's can be expressed by factorials too.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Like [Calculating $1+\frac13+\frac{1\cdot3}{3\cdot6}+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{3\cdot6\cdot9}+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}{3\cdot6\cdot9\cdot12}+\dots? $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746388/calculating-1-frac13-frac1-cdot33-cdot6-frac1-cdot3-cdot53-cdot6-cdot) using 
 [Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series),

$$nx=\dfrac12(-1)$$

$$\dfrac{n(n-1)x^2}2=\dfrac{1/2(1/2-1)}{2!}(-1)^2$$

Can you solve for $n,x?$