# Sum of an arithmetic infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to find the sum of the series :
$1+ \frac{2}{6} + \frac{2 \times 5}{6 \times 12} +  \frac{2 \times 5 \times 8}{6 \times 12 \times 18} + \cdots$..

I find out the $nth$ term to be
$u_n = \frac{2 \times 5 \times 8\times \cdots (3n+2)}{6 \times 12 \times 18 \cdots 6n}$.

After finding the $nth$ term I was unable to proceed.

Any insight will be happily accepted.Also looking for any tips or advices for solving this kind of problems.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like a job for the binomial theorem.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746388/calculating-1-frac13-frac1-cdot33-cdot6-frac1-cdot3-cdot53-cdot6-cdot

Comment: Quite helpful @labBhattacharjee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$u_n=\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\,\binom{-2/3}{n}\,.$$

Comment: Yes,I noted it..after that ?, I can't get..

Comment: Then, maybe you should take the hint by Lord Shark the Unknown into consideration.  Also, why didn't you take a look at the link given by MyGlasses and Did?