# Product of terms in a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial

*Okay so this question requires me to sum this series. My problem is however the product of the odd terms that appear in the sequence. I'm not able to write a general term for this sequence.*

> $$1+\frac{1}{1!}\cdot\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1\cdot3}{2!}\cdot(\frac{1}{4})^2+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{3!}\cdot(\frac{1}{4})^3+........... \infty$$

- The $\cdot$ represents the product of the two terms.
- $!$ represents the factorial of the specified number.

*My doubt is that after having the general term, how do I manipulate it to get the final sum? It makes no sense to me still.*

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks for giving this your time.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746388/calculating-1-frac13-frac1-cdot33-cdot6-frac1-cdot3-cdot53-cdot6-cdot

Answer (score 3):

$$a_n = 1\cdot3\cdot\dots\cdot(2n-1)\cdot\frac{1}{n!}\frac1{4^n} = \frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\dots\cdot2n}{2\cdot4\cdot\dots2n}\frac{1}{n!}\frac1{4^n}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n(n!)}\frac{1}{n!}\frac1{4^n}$$
$$=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}\left(\frac18\right)^n={2n\choose n}\left(\frac18\right)^n$$
So we have to evaluate
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2n\choose n}\left(\frac18\right)^n$$
Now using
$$(1-4x)^{-\frac12}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-4)^n{-\frac12\choose n}x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2n\choose n}x^n$$
We can conclude 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2n\choose n}\left(\frac18\right)^n=\sqrt2$$

Comment: Would you kindly explain how did you write that for that odd number multiplication sequence

Comment: @Tanuj See the below Siong's answer for the first term in case of $n=3$.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, but now that I have the general term, how do I manipulate it for the sum?

Comment: @Tanuj I added that part.

Comment: Thanks but I did not get what you did after that general term? Is that something I need to learn? What's the method, please clarify.

Comment: @Tanuj Yes it uses the generalized binomial series. Please refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialSeries.html

Comment: @Tanuj See the problem #10 in here https://www.hmmt.co/static/archive/february/solutions/2008/solutions-algebra-2008.pdf

Comment: how did you know that you have to use only $1-4x$ and not anything else?

Comment: @Tanuj Did you read the last link I sent you?

Comment: @Tanuj Could you accept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$1 \times 3 \times 5 = \frac{6!}{2(4)(6)}= \frac{(2 \times 3)!}{2^3(3!)}$$