# How to prove this beautiful series by using Taylor and Maclaurin series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I have been playing with Taylor and Maclaurin series lately and stumble on this beautiful identity. I don't know to expand the left hand side to yield the right hand side:
How to prove: $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} =1+\dfrac{1}{2}x^2+\dfrac{1 \cdot3}{2\cdot4}x^4+\dfrac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6}x^6+\dfrac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot 8}x^8...$
I can only expand this as followed:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = 1+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{3}{8}x^4+\frac{5}{16}x^6...,$$

How can you prove this by using Maclaurin series? 
I need two proofs, one in Maclaurin series and one in binomial theorem. Please don't use the sigma notation too much as I cannot see the pattern.

Comment: Just a thought, you might be able to use the fact that the LHS of your equation is the derivative of arcsin(x)...

Comment: @JG123 How do I get the beautiful coefficient this way?

Comment: You want people to give you two proofs?

Comment: @Calvin Khor, I just need to see how can I expand the first series by using binomial series and Maclaurin series. I am new to this so I don't know how to.

Comment: Well if you just want proof, just replace the LHS of the equation with d(arcsin(x))/dx and integrate both sides. See if the RHS of the resultant equation matches the Maclaurin series of arcsin(x). There is probably a more elegant way to prove your identity but this method came to me first.

Comment: That gives me a different series, namely $\arcsin(x)= x+\frac{1}{6}x^3+\frac{3}{40}x^5+\frac{5}{122}x^7...$

Comment: Can you simplify $\binom{-1/2}{n}$? Also, your comment about sigma notation strikes me as odd, since the whole point of sigma notation is to *say* what the pattern is (with formulas).

Answer (score 5):

Very simple: expand
$$\frac1{\sqrt{1-u}}=(1-u)^{-\tfrac12}$$
with the binomial series, and substitute $u=x^2$.

Note the general term of the binomial series is
$$(-1)^n\frac12\cdot\frac32\dotsm\frac{2n-1}2\,\frac{(-u)^n}{n!}= \frac{1\cdot 3\dotsm(2n-1)}{2^n n!}\,u^n=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\,u^{n}.$$
From the final formula, you can deduce instantly the Taylor series for $\arcsin x$.

Comment: That is the binomial coefficient  $\binom{-1/2}{n}$

Comment: If you wish, but I prefer an explicit form.

Comment: @Bernard can you do this in more steps? I have been using the binomial series and I can only expand it as the second series instead of the first one.

Comment: I don't see very well what to add – except perhaps, that the factor in the general term comes from $$-\frac12\Bigl(-\frac12-1\Bigr)\Bigl(-\frac12-2\Bigr)$$ and so on. Also you have to dispatch the powers of $2$ in the denominator among the factors of $n!$  to obtain $(2n)!!$.

Comment: @Bernard The general binomial series is $(1+x)^k=1+kx+\frac{k(k-1)}{2!}x^2+\frac{k(k-1)(k-2)}{3!}+\frac{k(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)}{4!}...$

Comment: How can I use this to obtain the first series?

Comment: It's this general formula that I appled, taking into account the denominators were systematically $2$. To obtain the first series, just  substitute $x^2$ to $u$.

Comment: @Bernard, can you do this in more details, I used the formula and get the series 2, not 1.

Comment: $(1-u)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=1+\frac{1}{2}u+\frac{-\frac{1}{2}(-\frac{1}{2}-1)u^2}{2!}+\frac{-\frac{1}{2}(-\frac{1}{2}-1)(-\frac{1}{2}-2)}{3!}...=1+\frac{1}{2}u+\frac{-\frac{1}{2}(-\frac{1}{2}-1)}{2!}u^2+\frac{-\frac{1}{2}(-\frac{1}{2}-1)(-\frac{1}{2}-2)}{3!}u^3$

Comment: I don't see how this leads up to series 1

Answer (score 4):

I have finally been able to derive the series after some manipulations:

The general formula for binomial series is:
$(1+x)^k=1+kx+\dfrac{k(k-1)}{2!}x^2+\dfrac{k(k-1)(k-2)}{3!}x^3+\dfrac{k(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)}{4!}x^4...$

$
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=(1-x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=1+(-\dfrac{1}{2})(-x^2)+\dfrac{(-\dfrac{1}{2})(-\dfrac{1}{2}-1)}{2!}(-x^2)^2+\dfrac{(-\dfrac{1}{2})(-\dfrac{1}{2}-1)(-\dfrac{1}{2}-2)}{3!}(-x^2)^3+\dfrac{(-\dfrac{1}{2})(-\dfrac{1}{2}-1)(-\dfrac{1}{2}-2)(-\dfrac{1}{2}-3)}{4!}(-x^2)^4...$

$=1+\dfrac{1}{2}x^2+\dfrac{(-\dfrac{1}{2})(-\dfrac{3}{2})}{2!}(x^4)+\dfrac{(-\dfrac{1}{2})(-\dfrac{3}{2})(-\dfrac{5}{2})}{3!}(-x^6)+\dfrac{(-\dfrac{1}{2})(-\dfrac{3}{2})(-\dfrac{5}{2})(-\dfrac{7}{2})}{4!}(x^8)...$

$=1+\dfrac{1}{2}x^2+\dfrac{1 \cdot3}{2^2\cdot2!}x^4+\dfrac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{2^3\cdot 3!}x^6+\dfrac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7}{2^4\cdot 4!}x^8...$

$=1+\dfrac{1}{2}x^2+\dfrac{1 \cdot3}{2\cdot4}x^4+\dfrac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6}x^6+\dfrac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot 8}x^8...$

$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(2n-1!!)}{2^nn!}x^{2n}$$

Answer (score 0):

At the site https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4657751, it was established that
\begin{equation*}
\biggl[\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}\,}\biggr]^{(k)}
=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}\,}\frac{k!}{2^k} \frac1{x^k}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{2^{j}(2j-1)!!}{j!}\binom{j}{k-j}\frac{x^{2j}}{(1-x^2)^{j}}, \quad k\ge0.
\end{equation*}
Therefore, we derive
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to0}\biggl[\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}\,}\biggr]^{(k)}
&=\frac{k!}{2^k} \lim_{x\to0}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{2^{j}(2j-1)!!}{j!}\binom{j}{k-j}\frac{x^{2j-k}}{(1-x^2)^{j}}\\
&=\begin{cases}
0, & k=2m+1\\
(2m)! \dfrac{(2m-1)!!}{(2m)!!}, & k=2m
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
for $k,m\ge0$. Consequently, we acquire
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}\,}
=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \dfrac{(2m-1)!!}{(2m)!!}x^{2m}, \quad |x|<1.
\end{equation*}