# Taylor series of $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I tried to expand $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ about $x=0$ with Taylor series directly
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
and calculated the following derivatives:
$$\begin{align}
f' (x) &= -\frac{1}{2}(1-x^2)^{-1.5}(-2x) = x(1-x^2)^{-1.5}\\
f'' (x) &= (1-x^2)^{-1.5}+3x^2(1-x^2)^{-2.5}\\
f''' (x) &=3x(1-x^2)^{-2.5}+3[2x(1-x^2)^{-2.5}+5x^3(1-x^2)^{-3.5}]\\
&=9x((1-x^2)^{-2.5}+15x^3(1-x^2)^{-3.5}  \\
f'''' (x) &=9[(1-x^2)^{-2.5}+5x(1-x^2)^{-3.5}]+15[3x^2(1-x^2)^{-3.5}+7x^4(1-x^2)^{-4.5}]\\
&=9(1-x^2)^{-2.5}+45x(1+x)(1-x^2)^{-3.5}+105x^4(1-x^2)^{-4.5}
\end{align}$$
Hence $f'(0)=0$, $f''(0)=1$, $f'''(0)=0$ and $f''''(0)=9$. Substituting into \eqref{eq1} yields
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\approx1+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{3}{8}x^4\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$
Then I realized that I can do [change of variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4230955/maclaurin-series-of-fx-frac1-sqrt1-x2) $y=x^2$ and expand $f(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y}}$ about $y=0$ using \eqref{eq1},  which is much more computational efficient:
$$f(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y}}\approx 1+\frac{1}{2}y+\frac{3}{8}y^2\tag{3}\label{eq3}$$
Substitute $x^2$ back to y:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\approx 1+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{3}{8}x^4 \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$
Since  \eqref{eq2} and \eqref{eq4} are equal to at least the 4-th order, both approaches give us the identical Taylor series.
By the way, this can be applied to [Einstein's mass energy equation](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/University_Physics_(OpenStax)/University_Physics_III_-_Optics_and_Modern_Physics_(OpenStax)/05%3A__Relativity/5.10%3A_Relativistic_Energy):
$$E_{total}=\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-{(\frac{v}{c})}^2}}\approx mc^2+\frac{1}{2}mv^2[1+\frac{3}{4}(\frac{v}{c})^2]\tag{5}\label{eq5}$$
The first term in \eqref{eq5} is the energy that the particle of mass m has when at rest or the rest energy and the second term is its kinetic energy.

Comment: You evaluated the derivatives incorrectly.

Comment: There is a standard power series for (1 + x)^ that would be worth familiarizing yourself with.

Comment: @Gary How so? You mean f(n)(0) != 0?

Comment: I did notice that wiki f(x) examples all are x to the first order such as sin(x), ln(1+x), exp(x), 1/(1-x),etc. Is this a pitfall?

Comment: For $f(x)=(1-x)^{-1/2}$ we have $f^{(n)}(x)={1\over 2}{3\over 2}\ldots {2n-1\over 2}(1-x)^{-1/2-n}$ hence $f^{(n)}(0)={1\over 2}{3\over 2}\ldots {2n-1\over 2}={(2n)!\over 4^nn!}.$

Comment: How about f(n)(0) for f(x)=(1-x^2)^-1/2?

Comment: @LeonChang Edit your question and write down your calculations, so we can pinpoint the mistake. Did you use the chain and product rules correctly?

Comment: @Gary You are right. I made an error in evaluating the derivatives.

Comment: Use Maclaurin series of $\arcsin x$ .

Comment: What is the question in this append?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I compared yours with Wiki's and mine, I think it should be $f^{(n)}(0) = \frac{(2n)!}{4^n (n!)^2}$, a square is missing on (n!).

Comment: The MacLaurin coefficient i.e. ${f^{(n)}(0)\over n!}$ contains $(n!)^2$ in the denominator but not $f^{(n)}(0).$

Comment: @LeonChang: After all these edits, there is no question in this post anymore. Please add one, otherwise it will get closed.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because after the edits it is no longer clear what the OP's question is.

Answer (score 1):

From a [table of Maclaurin series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html):
$$\arcsin x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(n+\tfrac12)}{\sqrt\pi\,(2n+1) n!}x^{2n+1}$$

Taking derivative of both sides we have
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(n+\tfrac12)}{\sqrt\pi\,n!}x^{2n}$$
which was not in the table.

Comment: I made a part of OP a tik tok post İ hope it is wellcome. 
Physics part important. https://vm.tiktok.com/ZM67fHkEw/

Comment: The way one derives the Maclaurin series of $\arcsin$ is by integrating the binomial series for $(1-x^2)^{-1/2}$. So this is a circular reasoning.

Comment: My purpose is just to show the use a table of information in mathematics.

Comment: @BobDobbs You used $\Gamma$ function in the expansion. I am not familiar with it. But wiki shows $\Gamma (n+\frac{1}{2})=\frac{(2n)!}{4^n n!}\sqrt\pi$, so it does match the regular formula. Is there a reason to use $\Gamma$ and introduce $\pi$?

Comment: @Gary Just to make sure, you mean $\sin^-1x=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2)} dx$ $\frac{d}{dx} \sin^-1 x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2)}. correct?

Comment: @Gary (edited) Just to make sure, you mean $\sin^{-1}x=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$ thus $\frac{d}{dx} \sin^{-1} x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. correct?

Comment: @LeonChang I  borrowed the formula from the list. It was given in this form.

Comment: Taylor expansion of $f(x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ is based on [Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)
$f(x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}$ which results in a [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial): 
$(2n-1)!! =\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}$. That shows in the final result of 
$\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n)!}{4^n (n!)^2}x^{2n}$