# If $y=\frac25+\frac{1\cdot3}{2!}\left(\frac25\right)^2 +\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{3!}\left(\frac25\right)^3+\ldots$ then what is the value of $y^2+2y$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-theorem

If
$$y=\frac25+\frac{1\cdot3}{2!}\left(\frac25\right)^2 +\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{3!}\left(\frac25\right)^3+\ldots$$
then what is the value of $y^2+2y$?

This is a question from my coaching material in which binomial theorem, multinomial theorem and binomial theorem with fractional and negative indices are covered. How do I approach this problem? What is the pattern in it?

Comment: You've been around for seven months. Didn't you notice that you are supposed to use MathJax?

Comment: Note that $1\cdot3\cdot 5=6!/2^3/3!$

Comment: If by pattern, you mean the summation, it appears to be

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2n-1)!!}{n!} \cdot \left( \frac{2}{5} \right )^n$$

where "$x!!$" is denoting the double factorial, for clarity's sake. I'm not really sure where to go from there myself though. My gut instinct is that definition which states the double factorial in terms of the regular factorial, but I wouldn't trust me on that.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746388/calculating-1-frac13-frac1-cdot33-cdot6-frac1-cdot3-cdot53-cdot6-cdot

Comment: Good ol' central binomial coefficients / Catalan numbers / Lagrange's inversion theorem. But before asking, *please try something*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks efforts and it is an abstract duplicate of *so many* questions.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I haven't studied Catalan numbers or Lagrange's inversion theorem. I had studied the basic binomial theorem as well as the binomial theorem formula for negative and fractional indices but at first it seemed to me to be unrelated to either. I had forgotten to use MathJax in my question and so I hadn't seen the similar questions.I just noticed that there were some similar questions after I got an answer. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall the binomial series  $(1+x)^\alpha=1+\alpha x+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2!}+\dots$

Let $x=\frac{-4}{5}$ and $\alpha=\frac{-1}{2}$. Then 
$$
\sqrt{5} = \left(1-\frac{4}{5}\right)^{\frac{-1}{2}} 
= 1 +\frac{2}{5} + \frac{1\cdot3}{2!}\cdot\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^2\cdot\left(\frac{-4}{5}\right)^2+\dots =y+1
$$
so $y^2+2y=(y+1)^2-1=4$

How to arrive at this: in your question you stated that you want to use the binomial theorem. The thing stopping you is that the numerators are decreasing by two each time, rather than by one. This suggests that the exponent is a half-integer. Once you have this it's just a matter of fiddling to come up with the values of $x$ and $\alpha$.

Answer (score 2):

Some hints:

We should look at the series
$$f(x):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty{(2k-1)!!\over k!}\>x^k\ .$$
I suggest you bring ${1\over\sqrt{1-2x}}$ into the game. This should allow you to obtain a nice expression for $f(x)$.