# Simplifying an infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Question:

The sum of $$1-\frac16+\frac16\times\frac14-\frac16\times\frac14\times\frac{5}{18}+\cdots$$

is:

A) $\frac23$
 B)$\frac{2}{\sqrt3}$  C)$\sqrt\frac23$   D)$\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$

---

After looking at the options I thought factoring into two's and three's would be a reasonable approach. The $\frac{5}{18}$ I considered factoring first as $\frac{2+3}{2\times3^2}$ and then as $\frac{3^2-2^2}{2\times3^2}$, but unfortunately I couldn't find a discernible pattern in either case. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $\frac14 = \frac{3}{12}$. The $n$-th term is
$(-1)^n\frac{(2n-1)!!}{6^n n!} = \left(-\frac{1}{12}\right)^n \binom{2n}{n}$. $\binom{2n}{n}$ is known as the [central binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient), look at its wiki entry and you will know how to compute the sum.

Comment: The pattern is completely unclear (to me, at least), but it does suggest an alternating sum of *decreasing* terms, from which we can infer that the answer is less than $1$ but greater than $1-{1\over6}={5\over6}=0.833333\ldots$.  This rules out the first three options (e.g., $\sqrt{2/3}=0.816496\ldots$), leaving only $\sqrt3/2=0.866025\ldots$ as a possibly correct answer.

Comment: Use find $$\left(1+\dfrac13\right)^{-1/2}$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I compared the terms in the binomial series and found the same result that you've stated. This yields D as the answer. Thanks for the help. 

I do have a question about this method though. When does it not hold? In other words, should I be checking for something before using it? Like convergence?

Comment: @s0ulr3aper07,  In https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746388/calculating-1-frac13-frac1-cdot33-cdot6-frac1-cdot3-cdot53-cdot6-cdot/746975#746975, find  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Convergence

Comment: Also keep in mind http://www.efunda.com/math/exp_log/series_exp.cfm