# Evaluate 1 + 3/4 + (3*5)/(4*8)+...

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Evaluate 
1 + 3/4 + (3.5)/(4.8) + (3.5.7)/(4.8.12) +...

I have simplified it to 
Summation ((2k+1)!)/(k!)(k!)) (1/8)^k  where k varies from 0 to infinity.

I am not able to to relate this sum with Taylor expansion of some function

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746388/calculating-1-frac13-frac1-cdot33-cdot6-frac1-cdot3-cdot53-cdot6-cdot

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are looking for
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^\infty (2k+1) \binom{2k}{k}\left( \frac18 \right)^k,
$$
so consider differentiating
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \binom{2k}{k} x^{2k+1},
$$
and using $(1/8)^k = (1/\sqrt8)^{2k}$

Answer (score 0):

the series is the binomial expansion of
$$
\bigg(1 - \frac12 \bigg)^{-\frac32}
$$

which gives the sum $2\sqrt{2}$

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you use \left and \right before parentheses and other delimiters they autosize based on what is inside.