# Show that: $1+\dfrac {1}{4}+\dfrac {1\cdot 4}{4\cdot 8}+\dfrac {1\cdot4\cdot7}{4\cdot8\cdot12}+ \dotsb = (2)^{2/3}$

Tags: solution-verification, binomial-theorem

Show that: $1+\dfrac {1}{4}+\dfrac {1\cdot4}{4\cdot8}+\dfrac {1\cdot4\cdot7}{4\cdot8\cdot12}+ \dotsb= (2)^{2/3}$

My attempt:

$$R.H.S=(2)^{\dfrac {2}{3}}$$
$$=(3-1)^{\dfrac {2}{3}}$$
$$=3^{\dfrac {2}{3}} [1+(-\dfrac {1}{3})]^{\dfrac {2}{3}}$$
$$=3^{\dfrac {2}{3}} [1+\dfrac {2}{3} \times \dfrac {-1}{3} + \dfrac {2}{3} \times \dfrac {\dfrac {2}{3} -1}{2!} \times (\dfrac {-1}{3})^2 +....$$

This doesn't seem to give the required resullt.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746388/calculating-1-frac13-frac1-cdot33-cdot6-frac1-cdot3-cdot53-cdot6-cdot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expand
$$\left(1-\frac34\right)^{-1/3}$$
by the binomial theorem.
One gets
$$4^{1/3}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1\cdot4\cdots(3n-2)}{4\cdot8\cdots(4n)}.$$