# Evaluate $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot \ldots (2r-1)}{r!}\left(\frac{2}{5} \right)^{r}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion, fubini-tonelli-theorems

> Evaluate $$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{1 \cdot 3  \cdots (2r-1)}{r!}\left(\frac{2}{5} \right)^{r}$$

Let $$y=x + \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot}{2!} x^2 + \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5}{3!} x^3+\ldots$$ be the given expression.(replacing $2/5$ with $x$)

After some manipulations,

$$y+1=(1-2x)\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Integrating and substituting $x=\dfrac{2}{5}$, we get $y=\sqrt{5}-1$.

Is there any other way to solve this question?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746388/calculating-1-frac13-frac1-cdot33-cdot6-frac1-cdot3-cdot53-cdot6-cdot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint:

It's a Taylor expansion for $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2x}}-1.$

Comment: @Qurultay I got it by the Taylor expansion. By the way, we obtain $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2x}}-1$ ;)

Answer (score 4):

$$S=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{1.3.5....(2r-1)}{r!}\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^r$$
$$\implies S=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2r)!}{r!~ r!} 5^{-r} =\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} {2r \choose r} 5^{-r}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4/5}}-1=\sqrt{5}-1.$$
Here we have used $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {2k \choose k} x^k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}$$

Answer (score 1):

To carry out the integration of
$y+1=(1-2x)\frac{dy}{dx}
$
we have
$\dfrac1{1-2x}
=\dfrac{y+1}{(y+1)'}
=(\ln(y+1))'
$
so
$\ln(y+1)
=\int \dfrac{dx}{1-2x}
=-\frac12\ln(1-2x)+c
$
so
$y+1 
=\dfrac{C}{\sqrt{1-2x}}
$
so
$y
=\dfrac{C}{\sqrt{1-2x}}-1
$.

At $x=0, y=0$ so
$C=1$.

Then,
for $x = \frac25$,
$y 
= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1/5}}-1
=\sqrt{5}-1
$.