# $\sum _ { n = 1 } ^ { \infty } n \binom {2 n} {n}( - z )^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients

According to wolframalpha,

$$\sum _ { n = 1 } ^ { \infty } n \binom {2 n} {n} ( - z )^n =  - \frac { 2 z } { ( 4 z + 1 ) ^ { 3 / 2 } } \text { when } 4 | z | < 1$$ However I have been unable to find how to get this result.

Comment: Start from the series expansion:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom {2n}nx^n=\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}$$

which is a consequence of the (generalized) binomial theorem, and converges for $|x|<\frac14$.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your efforts at answering this question. See [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/595055).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the generalized binomial theorem,$$(1+4z)^{-1/2}=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1/2)_n}{n!}4^nz^n=\sum_{n\ge0}\binom{2n}{n}(-z)^n.$$Differentiating,$$-2(1+4z)^{-3/2}=\sum_{n\ge0}\binom{2n}{n}(-1)^nnz^{n-1}=\sum_{n\ge1}\binom{2n}{n}(-1)^nnz^{n-1}.$$Multiplying by $z$,$$-2z(1+4z)^{-3/2}=\sum_{n\ge1}\binom{2n}{n}n(-z)^n.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$n\binom{2n}n=n\cdot\dfrac{(2n!)}{n! n!}=2\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$$

Now like [Calculating $1+\frac13+\frac{1\cdot3}{3\cdot6}+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{3\cdot6\cdot9}+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}{3\cdot6\cdot9\cdot12}+\dots? $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746388/calculating-1-frac13-frac1-cdot33-cdot6-frac1-cdot3-cdot53-cdot6-cdot/746975#746975).

comparing the expansion of $(1+x)^m$ with $$2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\binom{2n-1}{n-1} (-z)^{n-1}$$

$$mx=2\binom31(-z)^{2-1}\text{ and }\dfrac{m(m-1)}2x^2=2\binom52(-z)^{3-1}$$

to find $m=-\dfrac32, x=4z$