# Finding a generating function for $\{(n+2)C_{n+1}\}^\infty_{n=0}$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, catalan-numbers

I'm trying to come up with a generating function for $\{(n+2)C_{n+1}\}^\infty_{n=0}$ where $C_n$ is the $n$th Catalan number.

I know we can write $(n+2)C_{n+1} = 2(2n+1)C_n$. I also tried to follow this post: [Simplifying Catalan number recurrence relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337842/simplifying-catalan-number-recurrence-relation)

However I am getting somewhat stuck because of the added $(n+2)$ term.

Comment: Hint: If $c(x)=\sum\limits_nC_nx^n$ then $(xc(x))'=\sum\limits_n(n+1)C_nx^n$hence $\frac1x(xc(x))'=\sum\limits_n(n+2)C_{n+1}x^n$.

Comment: @Did Could you explain how you got to $(xc(x))' = ...$ I am a little confused on that part

Comment: You first: 1. If $a(x)=\sum\limits_na_nx^n$, what is $xa(x)$? 2. If $a(x)=\sum\limits_na_nx^n$, what is $a'(x)$?

Comment: @Did Thanks! $\frac{1}{x}(xc(x))' = \sum^\infty_n (n+2)C_{n+1}x^n$ makes perfect sense now. However, where do I go from here?

Comment: Well, you know $c(x)$ (or you should) hence you compute $\frac1x(xc(x))'$. What else...

Comment: @TheSalamander: I just did essentially this calculation as part of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1778058/12042).

Answer (score 1):

> Note that $$(n+1)C_n=\binom{2n}{n}\qquad\qquad n\geq 0$$ are the *[Central Binomial Coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient)* with the generating series representation
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}x^n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}\qquad\qquad |4x|<1\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> A generating function for $\{(n+2)C_{n+1}\}^\infty_{n=0}$ is therefore
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n= 0}^\infty& (n+2)C_{n+1}x^n\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+1)C_{n}x^{n-1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \binom{2n}{n}x^{n}\\
> &=\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}-1\right)
> \end{align*}

*Hint:* The representation (1) is an application of the *[binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* 
\begin{align*}
(1+x)^{\alpha}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{n}x^n\qquad |x|<1, \alpha\in\mathbb{C}
\end{align*}
and the relation
\begin{align*}
\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}=\frac{(-1)^n}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}
\end{align*}