# Find Sum of Series $2+\frac5{2!\cdot3}+\frac{5\cdot7}{3!\cdot3^2}+\frac{5\cdot7\cdot9}{4!\cdot3^3}+ \cdots\cdots $

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, factorial, summation-method

Find Sum of Series
$$2+\frac5{2!\cdot3}+\frac{5\cdot7}{3!\cdot3^2}+\frac{5\cdot7\cdot9}{4!\cdot3^3}+ \cdots\cdots $$

I tried breaking the terms into differences or finding a generalised term but did not get it right. Can someone please help me to proceed with this?

Comment: Are you sure the first term is $2$, and not $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the first term is $1$ (and not $2$ as written), the general term of the series is, for $n\geq 1$,
$$
a_n \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \frac{\prod_{k=2}^{n}(2k+1)}{n!3^{n-1}}
= \frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n}(2k+1)}{n!3^{n}}
= \frac{(2n+1)!}{n!3^{n}\prod_{k=1}^n(2k)}
= \frac{(2n+1)!}{n!3^{n}2^nn!}
= \frac{(2n+1)!}{(n!)^26^{n}}
$$
or, equivalently, $a_n= \binom{2n}{n}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^n$.

Now, either you work towards finding the general form for $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (2n+1) \binom{2n}{n}x^n$$
(a power series with radius of convergence $1/4$), which you can find by relating it to both
$
g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\binom{2n}{n}x^{n-1}
$
(recognize a derivative) and $
h(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \binom{2n}{n}x^{n}
$, since $$f(x) = 2xg(x)+h(x)\,;$$
or, by other means (there may be?) you establish that 
$f(1/6) = 3\sqrt{3}$, leading to 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = 3\sqrt{3}.
$$

Comment: If $n=1$, the product is empty, not 5 since it goes from 2 to $n$.

Comment: @martycohen for $n=1$, you get 1, the purported first term. $n=2$ gives 5/(6.3)

Comment: Sorry, the last part above should of course read 5/6, which matches the 5/(2! 3) from the question. I blame typing on my phone.

Comment: @martycohen but the question says first term=2 and can you please help me with the third step on how you managed the question or can you do it in simple terms without any complex terms (radius of convergence). I would be very grateful to you :)

Comment: @AdityaSingh take the result,  remove 1 (my first term), add 2 (your first term).

Comment: For the second question (how to derive the result once you know the form of the series, have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064216/generating-functions-and-central-binomial-coefficient), which solves the problem of computing $\sum_n \binom{2n}{n}x^n$ (and stems from wanting to compute $\sum_n (2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}x^n$ as in your case, but for $x=1/8$ instead of $1/6$)

Comment: @AdityaSingh And besides this (most relevant) question, see also [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69270/show-sum-limits-n-0-infty2n-choose-nxn-1-4x-1-2?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1849530/how-to-derive-the-close-form-of-a-power-series-with-a-2n-choose-n-binomial-c).

Comment: @AdityaSingh Let me know if something is still unclear.