# simplify $\sum_{n \geq0 } \binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{2^n}t^n$

Tags: generating-functions, binomial-theorem

How to simplify $$\sum_{n \geq0 } \binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{2^n}t^n$$
to show it equals $(1-2t)^{-1/2}$?

Here is a proof I came up with, but I use the fact that I know what the answer should be, so I am a bit dissatisfied with it. By the binomial theorem, the coefficient of $t^n$ in the  $(1-2t)^{-1/2}$
 is $\binom{-1/2}{n}(-2)^n$, and we want to show this equals $\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{2^n}$. This can be done via induction; it amounts to showing 
$$ 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2n-1)\cdot 2^n = (2n)(2n-1)\cdots (n+1)$$
which can be easily proved via induction.

I tried using $\binom{2n}{n}=\sum_{i}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{n-i}$

Comment: See Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#First_proof

Comment: the result should be $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t}}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner The OP already said so!

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30407/) (probably to the point that the present question is a duplicate).